# Why is my android app not reading in accessibility events?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an app to read on screen contents of other applications , I have tried every possible method but I am unable to get any logs of the onscreen contents.

Here's the mainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
        val txt =findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the accesibility service class

```
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        // Here you can read the on-screen contents of the current window
        // using the AccessibilityNodeInfo class.
        val nodeInfo = event?.source
        val text = nodeInfo?.text?.toString()
        Log.d("MyAccessibilityService", "onAccessibilityEvent: $text")
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // This method is called when the AccessibilityService is interrupted.
    }
}
```

The manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
            android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The accessibility config

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="com.example.app1,com.example.app2"
    android:settingsActivity=".MainActivity"/>`
```

I expected to get a back a log of onscreen text in the logcat but apparently the accesibilty service class is never called so it doesn't even show anything if i put a log inside it

I have even enable accessibility in settings

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in it to see if it's even getting called?  And have you set it as the active accessibility service on the device?